# Firebase Database printa data and get the value of each element

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, shopping-cart

I have a problem taking the data taken from firebase and then adding it to the cart. Maybe I'm wrong way.

First print the data based on the category.
I add with .html().
My problem is:
There are 3 products with 3 different names(Chair,table,sofa), I would like to take the value it has at that time in its html += "<a onclick='test();' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left'
i click i want retrive the for ex. the second element. 
How can I tell them apart? and how do I take values?
Is it not possible using this type of function?

```
function retriveImageShop(scelta){
  }
var leadsRef = firebase.database().ref().child("products").orderByChild("categoria").equalTo(scelta);
leadsRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  var html = "";
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      var counter = counter +1;
      var name = childSnapshot.child("name").val();
      var prezzo = childSnapshot.child("prezzo").val();
      var imgurl =childSnapshot.child("imgurl").val();


          html +=  "<div class='col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-12 col-xl-6'>"; 
          html += " <div class='single-product-wrapper'>"; 
          html += " <div class='product-img'>"; 
          html += "<img src='"+imgurl+"' alt=''>"; 
          html += "<img class='hover-img' src='"+imgurl+"' alt=''>";
          html += "</div>";
          html += "<div class='product-description d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between'>"; 
          html +="<div class='product-meta-data'>" ;
          html += "<div class='line'></div>";
          html +="<p id='price' class='product-price'>"+prezzo+"</p>" ;
          html +=" <a href='product-details.html'>" ;
          html += "<h6 id='name'>"+name+"</h6>";
          html += " </a>";
          html += "</div>";
          html += " <div class='ratings-cart text-right'>";
          html += "<div class='ratings'>";
          html += "<i class='fa fa-star' aria-hidden='true'></i>";
          html += "<i class='fa fa-star' aria-hidden='true'></i>";
          html += "<i class='fa fa-star' aria-hidden='true'></i>";
          html += "<i class='fa fa-star' aria-hidden='true'></i>";
          html += "<i class='fa fa-star' aria-hidden='true'></i>";
          html += "</div>";
          html += "<div class='cart'>";
          html += "<a onclick='test();' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' title='Add to Cart'>";
          html += "<img src='img/core-img/cart.png' alt=''></a>";
          html += "</div>";
          html += "</div>";
          html += "</div>";
          html += "</div>";
          html += "</div>";



    })

      $("#productt").html(html);



});

}
```